# Docker Compose : yaml: line 9: did not find expected tag URI

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a problem that I don't understand at all. Somebody knows how to solve this problem and why it happens?

> yaml: line 9: did not find expected tag URI

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./
      target: ripoty_php
      args:
        SYMFONY_VERSION: ${SYMFONY_VERSION:-}
        SKELETON: ${SKELETON:-symfony/website-skeleton}
        STABILITY: ${STABILITY:-stable}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      MERCURE_URL: ${CADDY_MERCURE_URL:-http://caddy/.well-known/mercure}
      MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL: https://${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}/.well-known/mercure
      MERCURE_JWT_SECRET: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}

 ...

volumes:
  php_socket:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```

I use Kevin Dunglas' repo: [Repository](https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker)

Comment: Where did you translate the variables used in the args section? And can you also post the Dockerfile, that way other can try to reproduce.

Comment: Please, post the command line which calls docker compose.

Comment: I've updated the post, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you change the value of `!ChangeMe!` with something that don't start with `!` it should work.

Best regards,
Daniel